# access a class file from local path to java code

Tags: java, testng

i am trying to execute testng test case from java code
so i got below code from testng.

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Run2.class });
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
```

now i want to provide .class(i.e. Run2) file from local path.

I don't want to place this class to my current package

please tell me how to access a .class file from local location to java code so that it will run the testng testcase from any location where class is present.

Comment: use Class.forName("class name").getClass().

Answer (score 0):

Try using an instance of `java.net.URLClassloader` with the url of the folder. And then use `loadClass(classname)` to load the class.

Comment: thanks
when i tried this i got the malformed exception

java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: d

 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:592)
 
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
 
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
 
 at TestNGRunClass.main(TestNGRunClass.java: